# Check if a URL exists then open in iframe

Tags: ajax, iframe

Currently, I open a url with

```
window.open("#iframeid", myurl);
```

However, ideally I want to check if the url exists before loading it.
I've changed my code to the following, but I cannot see where I'm going wrong.
Nothing appears to happen.
if I change .add to .src, I get an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
  url: myurl,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){
    $("#iframeid").add(data);
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert("didn't work");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code based on the statusCode:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        dataType: 'html',
          statusCode: {
              200: function(){
                  //run your success code
              },
              404: function() {
                  alert( "page not found" );
              }
          }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try, however, I believe it is the setting the code in the iframe that is the problem.